# this .find() not working with jQuery slideToggle

Tags: jquery, find, this, slidetoggle

I have the following code at jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3fp4Q/8/ and can't seam to get it to work. I want the list of books and socks to be displayed (toggled) when the Title is clicked.
Any help much appreciated. Thanks

HTML:

```
<div id="accordion">

<h2>Books</h2>

<ul>
    <li>Book 1</li>
    <li>Book 2</li>
    <li>Book 3</li>
    <li>Book 4</li>
</ul>

<h2>Socks</h2>

<ul>
    <li>Sock 1</li>
    <li>Sock 2</li>
    <li>Sock 3</li>
    <li>Sock 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#accordion").find("ul").css("display", "none");
jQuery("#accordion").find("h2").on("click", function(){
        jQuery(this).find("ul").slideToggle();
});
});
```

Comment: `find()` searches for descendent elements. in the click handler, `this` refers to the `h2` which does not have any `ul` descendents. try `siblings()` or `next()` instead.

Comment: @jbabey thanks - didn't know that about it only searching descendents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fp4Q/10/)

`ul` is not a child element of `h2` Hence it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

use `.next()`   *as `ul` is next to your `h2`*

```
jQuery(this).next("ul").slideToggle();
```